# Does this C inheritance implementation contain undefined behavior?

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer

```
struct parent
{
    char a;
    char b;
};

struct child
{
    struct parent parent;
    int c;
    char d;
};

struct grandchild
{
    struct child child;
    long e;
};

void print_parent_val(struct parent *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", p->a);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct grandchild g;
    g.child.parent.a = 69;
    print_parent_val((struct parent *)&g);
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles (no warnings) and runs fine and prints `69` as expected. I have never seen any code that implements this inheritance technique so I'm very hesitant to see this as "OK".

**EDIT:** What about converting the grandchild to just a child? Is the mid-generation conversion also possible?

```
void print_parent_val(struct child *c)
{
    printf("%c\n", c->d);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct grandchild g;
    g.child.parent.a = 69;
    g.child.d = 'w';
    print_parent_val((struct child *)&g);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this known as type punning? Like in Win32, `NMHDR` and structures whose first memeber is a pointer to `NMHDR`? I'm not sure

Comment: You may also want to look at `man 3 offsetof` which is related to your question.

Comment: You may never have seen code that implements that technique, but I've certainly *written* such code.  After convincing myself that its behavior is well-defined, based on essentially the same argument that Sourav presents in his answer.  I'm confident that I was nowhere near the first to write such code.

Comment: Of course, you don't actually need the casts.  You can take the address of the appropriate member instead.  Eg, `print_parent_val(&g.child.parent)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can see, there's no scope of undefined behaviour *here*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.2.1, *Structure and union specifiers*, (*emphasis mine*)

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.**

So, with the current snippet (and approach), you should be good to go.

Comment: I've made some edits to my question as you can see, but I believe this quote answers it as well.

Comment: You're correct that the memory layout of the struct would allow for this to work, _if_ strict aliasing weren't a thing. With `-fno-strict-aliasing`, this is the correct answer!

Comment: @HaldeanBrown There is this explicit mention about no padding at beginning, so how does this violate strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar I believe you're correct, as long as you stick to the first member variable. :)

Comment: @HaldeanBrown there is no violation of strict aliasing with this technique. There _is_ a `parent` object at the beginning of the child.

Comment: @HaldeanBrown: per the specification in 6.5 paragraph 7, it is explicitly allowed to alias like this, and it does not violate strict aliasing...